# Action Hook Inside Wordpress Plugin Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, http-post

I'm developing a Wordpress plugin and I'm having trouble getting $_POST data using an action inside my shortcode. The form I'm parsing is on a page that I've added my shortcode to.

Here's what I've got:

```
function wpd_post_parse() {

    $string = 'wp hook: ' . var_dump($_POST) . "\r\n";

    //$string = 'wp hook: first name: ' . $_POST["first_name"] . "\r\n";
    //$string .= 'wp hook: last name: ' . $_POST["last_name"] . "\r\n";
    //$string .= 'wp hook: email: ' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";

    $fileName = dirname(__FILE__) . '/log.txt';     

    file_put_contents($fileName, $string, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    //file_put_contents($fileName, $string, FILE_APPEND);

    /*
    if (!empty($_POST)){

        $string = 'wp hook: ' . var_dump($_POST) . "\r\n";

        $fileName = dirname(__FILE__) . '/log.txt';     

        file_put_contents($fileName, $string, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        //file_put_contents($fileName, $string, FILE_APPEND);

    }else{

        $string = 'wp hook: POST empty' . "\r\n";

        $fileName = dirname(__FILE__) . '/log.txt';     

        file_put_contents($fileName, $string, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
    */

}

function mgc_init(){

    $htmlStr = 'Hello World!' . "\r\n";

    $fileName = dirname(__FILE__) . '/log.txt';

    file_put_contents($fileName, $htmlStr, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    //file_put_contents($fileName, $htmlStr, FILE_APPEND);  

    //Add hook to capture $_POST data
    add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpd_post_parse' );

}

add_shortcode('mgc','mgc_init'); //put this shortcode [mgc] on page in Wordpress
```

**UPDATE:** Thanks for your help so far. I'm trying to get a $_POST value (first name) on form submit but the value isn't inside $_POST["first_name"]. All that gets printed to the file is "wp hook: first name: " Here's how the code looks now:

```
//Capture the $_POST data
function wpd_post_parse() {

    //$string = 'wp hook: ' . var_dump($_POST) . "\r\n";

    $string = 'wp hook: first name: ' . $_POST["first_name"] . "\r\n";
    //$string .= 'wp hook: last name: ' . $_POST["last_name"] . "\r\n";
    //$string .= 'wp hook: email: ' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";

    $fileName = dirname(__FILE__) . '/log.txt';     

    file_put_contents($fileName, $string, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    //file_put_contents($fileName, $string, FILE_APPEND);

    /*
if (!empty($_POST)){

    $string = 'wp hook: ' . var_dump($_POST) . "\r\n";

    $fileName = dirname(__FILE__) . '/log.txt';     

    file_put_contents($fileName, $string, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    //file_put_contents($fileName, $string, FILE_APPEND);

}else{

    $string = 'wp hook: POST empty' . "\r\n";

    $fileName = dirname(__FILE__) . '/log.txt';     

    file_put_contents($fileName, $string, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
*/

//exit;
}

function mgc_init(){

    $htmlStr = 'Hello World!' . "\r\n";

    $fileName = dirname(__FILE__) . '/log.txt';

    file_put_contents($fileName, $htmlStr, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    //file_put_contents($fileName, $htmlStr, FILE_APPEND);  

    do_action( 'wpd_post_parse' );

}

add_shortcode('mgc','mgc_init'); //put this shortcode [mgc] on thedinnerdaily.com/subscribe/ page in Wordpress 

add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpd_post_parse' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach didn't work and it caused site-wide problems on Wordpress. I moved my code off of the registration page and onto the completed form's re-direct page. From there I was able to capture the form data I was looking for.